# How can I load the product collection without some products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection, product-collection

Actually, I want to load the product collection except for some products. I have the product ids that I don't want in the collection. For example, the product ids that I don't want in the product collection is like

```
$productIds = array(10,20,30);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
$productIds = array(10,20,30);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
```

Comment: Thanks, Dhiren . It works fine with [->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));]

Answer (score 5):

Use [`addIdFilter()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php#L597) with the second parameter `$exclude` set to true, to invert the filter:

```
$productCollection->addIdFilter($productIds, true)
```

Answer (score 4):

some time `not in` not work without `addFieldToSelect` I will always use this

```
$productIds = array(10,20,30)
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')   
             ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
```